# Excel 2016 will not let me assign a worksheet to a variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm an experienced C/C++/Java/C# developer, trying VBA for the first time in Excel 2016, and hit a baffling problem out of the gate with the following complete macro:

```
Sub AddDataToSheet1()
10  Dim ws As Worksheet
20  ws = Worksheets(1)
30  ws.Activate
40  ws.Range("A1").Value = "Apple Pie"
End Sub
```

At line 20, it crashes with the error:

```
Runtime error '91'
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Um... I'm trying to set it? This is the very first workbook created in a brand new install of Office 365 on Windows 10 Pro. The workbook has two worksheets in it, `"Main Sheet"` and `"Aux Sheet 1"`, in that order.

If I change line 20 to:

```
20  ws = Sheets(1)
```

the same error occurs. It also occurs if I try to index by the worksheet name using either Worksheets or Sheets, eg

```
20  ws = Sheets("Main Sheet")
```

Even qualifying with the Application results in the same error:

```
20  ws = Application.Workheets("Main Sheet")
```

Intellisense seems to believe that Sheets, Worksheets, Application.Sheets, and Application.Worksheets are all valid objects, with _Default(index) as an available operation.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: You SET objects but assign values to variables. `SET ws = Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Doh! I somehow overlooked that in all the sample code I combed over while trying to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: @Jeeped, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SET objects but assign values to variables. You need to `SET ws = Worksheets(1)` .

```
Sub AddDataToSheet1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, str as string
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Apple Pie"
    str = ws.Range("A1").Value
    debug.print str
End Sub
```